While importing 'run', an ImportError was raised:
(abess_002_env)─(mikado㉿ilak)-[~/Documents/Projects/flask/abess_002]
└─$ flask db init
Error: While importing 'run', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikado/Documents/Projects/flask/abess_002/abess_002_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 245, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/mikado/Documents/Projects/flask/abess_002/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = create_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mikado/Documents/Projects/flask/abess_002/app/__init__.py", line 20, in create_app
    from app import routes, models
  File "/home/mikado/Documents/Projects/flask/abess_002/app/routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app, db
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (/home/mikado/Documents/Projects/flask/abess_002/app/__init__.py)


Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'db'.

i ran into the above error while trying to initialize my db migrations
here is my run.py:
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


app/init.py:
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'login'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login.init_app(app)

    from app import routes, models
    return app


requirements.txt:
alembic==1.13.2
blinker==1.8.2
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
Flask==3.0.3
Flask-Login==0.6.3
Flask-Migrate==4.0.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
greenlet==3.0.3
idna==3.8
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
Mako==1.3.5
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
requests==2.32.3
SQLAlchemy==2.0.34
stripe==10.10.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
urllib3==2.2.2
Werkzeug==3.0.4
WTForms==3.1.2


It is expected to initialize my migration

Could you provide tree schema of your project directories, please
